# RSyntaxTextArea always showing white color for number column

Tags: java, swing, rsyntaxtextarea

[image]

If someone can help with this issues please

Comment: I always tried something like setCodeFoldingEnabled(false), but with no luck

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to load an XML theme. Since your application already has a dark theme, this will be suitable for you

```
try {
          InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/org/fife/ui/rsyntaxtextarea/themes/dark.xml");
          Theme theme = Theme.load(in);
          theme.apply(txaIDE);//WHERE txaIDE IS YOUR RSYNTAXTEXTAREA INSTANCE
      } catch (Exception e) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, e.toString());
      }
```

I hope this helps